# First test suite failing with allure-rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, selenium-webdriver, allure

I'm working on integrating allure into my tests but have come across a problem with the first test suite failing and returning a undefined method `find_element' for nil:NilClass error with every test in the suite. The tests run as expected when I'm not using allure and the same thing happens regardless of what suite is run.

I've had a look into it and it seems the before and after hooks in my spec helper aren't being used in the failed tests. Any ideas what could be causing this?

```
require 'rspec'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'allure-rspec'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'uuid'
require 'pathname'

RSpec.configure do |c|


c.include AllureRSpec::Adaptor


c.expect_with :rspec do |c|
    ### Enable both should and expect syntax ###
    c.syntax = [:should, :expect]
end

c.before(:all) do
    #Start the Phantom-js driver before running any headless tests
    case ENV['browser']
    when 'headless'
        ## Run in command line before a headless test: phantomjs --webdriver=8001
        system('start cmd /k phantomjs --webdriver=8001')
        sleep 3
    end
end

c.before(:each) do  
    #Find the browser to the used and set the driver to the appropriate one
    case ENV['browser']
    when 'chrome'
        @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
        #@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:remote, url: 'http://localhost:5555/wd/hub', desired_capabilities: :chrome)
    when 'ie'
        @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :internet_explorer
        #@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:remote, url: 'http://localhost:5555/wd/hub', desired_capabilities: :ie)
    when 'firefox'
        @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
        #@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:remote, url: 'http://localhost:5555/wd/hub', desired_capabilities: :firefox)
    when 'headless'
        @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :remote, url: 'http://localhost:8001'
    end
    #Maximize the browser
    @driver.manage.window.maximize
    @driver.get ENV['base_url']
end

c.after(:each) do |c|
    #Takes a screen shot if an exception is thrown and attaches it to the allure XML when running Rake tests
    if c.exception != nil
        $failure = true

            c.attach_file("screenshot", File.new(@driver.save_screenshot(File.join(Dir.pwd, "test_reports/allure/#{UUID.new.generate}.png"))))

    end 
    @driver.quit
end 

end

AllureRSpec.configure do |c|
   #Outputs the Allure XML
   c.output_dir = "test_reports/allure"
end
```

Comment: which versions of allure and rspec are you using?

Comment: I'm using 3.2 at the moment

Comment: Could you please provide a sample project to reproduce the problem?